# Options avaiable when adapting JPA application to another database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new to JPA and am facing a problem with a JPA application.

I am working on an application that is mapped to its current database using the concept of BaseEntity, where all entities extend this one. This BaseEntity has the "id" column mapped as following:

```
/**
 * Getter for the id.
 * 
 * @return id Represents the primary key column of the record.
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id",nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

All entities extend this and this works fine with its current database.

Now I have the task of adapting this application to start using another database that is kind of similar, but the main difference is that on this other database, all the tables have their primary keys named as "table_name_" + "id", which doesn't work with my current mapping. Changing the database columns is not an option for me, I only have control over the application code.

What options do I have here? What would be the best pratice? I thought about somehow getting the class name during runtime and attaching it to the column. Would that be a good idea? I'm using hibernate by the way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "orm.xml" is your friend. One version for one database, and one version for another database. Then you don't need to go in and change Java files when swapping between databases, just the appropriate orm.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a specific mapping file for the *other database*.

But as long as you've got no other columns that end with `_id`, it could be easier to use a custom `NamingStrategy` for your *current database*.

Add the ids matching the *other database*:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "my_table_id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

For your *current database* you extend the `DefaultNamingStrategy`:

```
public class CurrentDatabaseNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

    public String columnName(String columnName) {
      if (propertyName.endsWith("_id")) {
        return "id";
      }
    }

}
```

Now you can defined that one for your *current database* in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit...>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="CurrentDatabaseNamingStrategy" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Unfortunately the `NamingStrategy` does not get the entity class or table name as parameter - so you can't stick to your old `Column` annotations with that solution.

Answer (score -1):

Simply annotate your entity class with this:

```
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="table_name_id")),
})
```

Comment: What's the difference to just changing `@Column(name="id")`? The OP didn't wanted to overwrite the ID of a superclass or an embeddable, but wanted to have two different ID columns for the _same class_ for two different databases.